# @Caching in spring cache

Tags: spring, caching

I'm used cache in page list.

I want to 1~5 page cached.

So,

```
@Cacheable(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, #pageIndex, #pagePerNumber)", condition = "#pageIndex < 5")
```

Keys like:

```
'brandon@[EventChainServiceImpl]0/10'

'brandon@[EventChainServiceImpl]1/10'

'brandon@[EventChainServiceImpl]2/10'
```

So,

```
@Caching(evict = {
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 0, 5)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 0, 10)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 0, 25)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 0, 50)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 1, 5)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 1, 10)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 1, 25)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 1, 50)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 2, 5)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 2, 10)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 2, 25)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 2, 50)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 3, 5)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 3, 10)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 3, 25)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 3, 50)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 4, 5)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 4, 10)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 4, 25)"),
    @CacheEvict(value = "cacheData", key = "T(com.insoft.pacific.util.CacheKeyGenerator).cacheKey(#root.targetClass, 4, 50)") })
```

How can I simplify this?

Comment: I have indented your keys by 4 spaces so its looks more attractive.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can inject the CacheManager and ..., like this:

```
@Autowired
CacheManager cacheManager;
public Object doSomething() {
    Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("yourCacheName");
    for (String key : yourKeyIterator) {
        cache.evict(key);
    }
}
```

I think it is harmful to the performance because calling cache.evict(key) much times.

I think calling the native cache implemention methods is better.

```
(Ehcache)cache.getNativeCache()...
```